# how to create dataTable server side

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

im new for learning about dataTable server side. please explain me about server side dataTable code. i know how server side work but i dont how to code? please explain me.

i have searching from google and i got it code for ajax but i dont know its dataTable server side or not. when i running thats code it took a long time. the question is,

is this my code was dataTable server side or not?

This is my modal code :

```
<?php
class M_barang extends CI_Model
{

    function barang_list()
    {
        $hasil = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM villages");
        return $hasil->result();
    }
}
```

This is my Controllers code :

```
<?php
class Barang extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_barang');
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('v_barang');
    }

    function data_barang()
    {
        $data = $this->m_barang->barang_list();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

This is my View :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>List Barang</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/bootstrap.css' ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/jquery.dataTables.css' ?>">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="page-header">Data
                <small>Barang</small>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="mydata">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>District ID</th>
                        <th>Kelurahan</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="show_data">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/jquery.js' ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/bootstrap.js' ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js' ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            tampil_data_barang(); //pemanggilan fungsi tampil barang.

            $('#mydata').dataTable();

            //fungsi tampil barang
            function tampil_data_barang() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/barang/data_barang',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var html = '';
                        var i;
                        var x = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            x++;
                            html += '<tr>' +
                                '<td>' + x + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + data[i].id + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + data[i].district_id + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>';
                        }
                        $('#show_data').html(html);
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

please show me simple dataTable serverside or if my code was server side? please fix it my code.

Comment: can you print your  echo json_encode($data);?

Comment: You should check out datatables documentation. They have callback functions to populate the table. doing it this way won't work. also check out ignited datatables. it is a helper library for making the json part easier.

Comment: this tutorial will help you out with that problem. https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-datatables-server-side-processing/

Comment: Please check https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables. This library is the best solution for datatable serverside in codeigniter